# Building a 32-bit app in 64-bit Ubuntu

Tags: gcc, 32bit-64bit, ld

After hours of googling, I decide to give up and ask you experts. I am trying to build a 32-bit application (xgap if anyone interested) in my 64 Ubuntu 11.10. I added the **CFLAGS=-m32** and the **LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib32** in the makefile. The objects are built into 32 bit fine. The last step is to link all the objects and libraries for X windows into this executable---xgap. Somehow it keeps giving me this error:

```
gcc -o xgap xcmds.o utils.o gapgraph.o gaptext.o pty.o popdial.o xgap.o selfile.o   -L/usr/lib32 -lXaw -lXmu -lXt -lXext -lX11  -lSM -lICE

/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib32/libXmu.so when searching for -lXmu
...

/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `xcmds.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
...
```

I have installed **ia32-libs** and **mutilib support**. I think I just need to force the linker to generate a i386 output. I tried to put two **ld** flags in my gcc command as shown above: **-melf_i386** and **-oformat elf32-i386**. But what happens is that gcc doesn't search for the 32 bit library in **/usr/lib32** anymore. I wonder if I need to put those flags in some fixed order?

Thanks for any idea and help!

**EDIT**: when I add the -m32 flag in my last gcc command (the linking stage I believe), even if I have the -L/usr/lib32 flag in place, gcc doesn't search in /usr/lib32 anymore ( really weird...) and generates the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../libXaw.so when searching for -lXaw
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libXaw.so when searching for -lXaw
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXaw
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any one has any idea why this happens? I am using the auto tool to configure and make. I am really good at modifying those script files.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355436/how-to-compile-32-bit-apps-on-64-bit-ubuntu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use link with `-m32` as well.

```
gcc -m32 -o xgap xcmds.o utils.o gapgraph.o gaptext.o pty.o popdial.o xgap.o selfile.o   -L/usr/lib32 -lXaw -lXmu -lXt -lXext -lX11  -lSM -lICE
```

All things considered, I think you should be able to drop the `-L/usr/lib32` when using `-m32`.

Comment: when I did you suggestion, gcc doesn't search in /usr/lib32 anymore. It searches in /usr/lib/. Error messages as follows:/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../libXaw.so when searching for -lXaw
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libXaw.so when searching for -lXaw
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXaw
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Do you have any idea as to why this happens?

Comment: It seems Ubuntu is doing something differently than what I would expect. Or the `ia32-libs` package is not what you expect. It doesn't magically contain every 32-bit counterpart for all the 64-bit libraries on your system, only a few core things. You'll need a `lib32-libXau` or something, not sure how Debian/Ubuntu handles that.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. I think that **gcc** was expecting a static library archive. I used the **getlibs** script from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=474790 to download all the **.a** archives needed for linking. Then **gcc** worked. I think **gcc** did search in **/usr/lib32** directory but didn't find the  **.a** archives so went on to search in the standard directory which is **/usr/lib**, where it finds the incompatible ***.so** files.

But then the question is: the ***.so** files in **/usr/lib32/** from package **ia32-libs** doesn't really have the libraries needed for linking? What are those files in **/usr/lib32/** used for?