# Can't create a snap with Snapcraft

Tags: ubuntu, rust, ubuntu-20.04, snapcraft, alacritty

I'm trying to create a snap for Alacritty on ubuntu 20.04 x64. Creating an executable with `cargo build --release` works fine. Creating a snap using `snapcraft` gives error message:

```
note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find Scrt1.o: No such file or directory
      /usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
      collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

error: aborting due to previous error
error: could not compile `libc`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
Failed to run '/root/.cargo/bin/cargo +stable build --release' for 'allacrity-source': Exited with code 101.
Verify that the part is using the correct parameters and try again.
Run the same command again with --debug to shell into the environment if you wish to introspect this failure.
```

I have both of the mentioned libraries installed, Scrt1.o and crti.o. I went further and checked for their location and edited my ~/.profile to include `export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib32:/usr/libx32:$LIBRARY_PATH`. This never helped either. How can I solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a possible 64bit vs 32bit library mis-match.

[Compiling problems: cannot find crt1.o](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329887/compiling-problems-cannot-find-crt1-o)

[While building 32-bit executable file in 64-bit Linux I get crt1.o: No such file even with the -m32 flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724540/while-building-32-bit-executable-file-in-64-bit-linux-i-get-crt1-o-no-such-file)