# How to Compile 32-bit Apps on 64-bit Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, 64-bit, 32-bit

I'm trying to compile a 32-bit C application on Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS 64-bit using gcc 4.8. I'm getting linker error messages about incompatible libraries and `skipping -lgcc`. What do I need to do to get 32 bit apps compiled and linked?

Comment: A related link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58654288/how-to-make-compiler-generate-a-elf32-x86-64-format-object-file

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To get Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS 64-bit to compile gcc 4.8 32-bit programs, you'll need to do two things.

1. Make sure all the 32-bit gcc 4.8 development tools are completely installed:

   `sudo apt-get install lib32gcc-4.8-dev`
2. Compile programs using the -m32 flag

   `gcc pgm.c -m32 -o pgm`

Comment: Note that the `-m32` flag is specific to 32-bit x86. You need different flags to compile for 32-bit ARM, RISC-V, etc.

Answer (score 110):

This is known to work on Ubuntu 16.04 through 22.04:

```
sudo apt install gcc-multilib g++-multilib
```

Then a minimal hello world:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    puts("hello world");
    return 0;
}
```

compiles without warning with:

```
gcc -m32 -ggdb3 -O0 -pedantic-errors -std=c89 \
  -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main.out main.c
```

And

```
./main.out
```

outputs:

```
hello world
```

And:

```
file main.out
```

says:

```
main.out: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=87c87a83878ce7e7d23b6236e4286bf1daf59033, not stripped
```

and:

```
qemu-i386 main.out
```

also gives:

```
hello world
```

but fails on an `x86_64` executable with:

```
./main.out: Invalid ELF image for this architecture
```

Furthermore, I have:

- run the compiled file in a 32 bit VM
- compiled and run an [IA-32 C driver + complex IA-32 code](https://github.com/cirosantilli/assembly-cheat/tree/c388cd30066aeaade24f3893ab50d43e7d5cfdd5/ia-32)

So I think it works :-)

See also: [Cannot find crtn.o, linking 32 bit code on 64 bit system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807581/cannot-find-crtn-o-linking-32-bit-code-on-64-bit-system)

It is a shame that this package conflicts with the cross compilers like `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf` https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-defaults/+bug/1300211

Running versions of the question:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12956/how-do-i-run-32-bit-programs-on-a-64-bit-debian-ubuntu
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/how-to-run-32-bit-app-in-ubuntu-64-bit

We are able to run 32-bit programs directly on 64-bit Ubuntu because the Ubuntu kernel is configured with:

```
CONFIG_IA32_EMULATION=y
```

according to:

```
grep CONFIG_IA32_EMULATION "/boot/config-$(uname -r)"
```

whose help on the [kernel source tree](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.19/arch/x86/Kconfig#L2866) reads:

```
Include code to run legacy 32-bit programs under a
64-bit kernel. You should likely turn this on, unless you're
100% sure that you don't have any 32-bit programs left.
```

This is in turn possible because x86 64 bit CPUs have a mode to run 32-bit programs that the Linux kernel uses.

TODO: what options does `gcc-multilib` get compiled differently than `gcc`?

Comment: (plus one) for obsessively validating the result.

Comment: As an aside, for C++ projects `g++-multilib` package should be installed.

Comment: Doesn't work in podman/docker container with Ubuntu 18.04. As a matter of fact, I don't see why would it ever work, because the mentioned gcc-multilib packages [barely has any files](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/gcc-multilib/filelist), and certainly it has no libraries in them.

Comment: So, what helped for me in a docker/podman container with Ubuntu, is to install `lib32gcc-10-dev` *(worth noting, the 10 version in my case is from PPA; without PPA it would be a lower version)*.

Comment: But what if you need to link libraries?

Comment: @user2134488 you'll likely have to build them yourself, or obtain them yourself and point GCC to them. This approaches more and and more a proper cross compilation setup.

Answer (score 12):

Multiarch installation is supported by adding the architecture information to the package names you want to install (instead of installing these packages using alternative names, which might or might not be available).

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/107249/9452) for more information on (modern) multiarch installations.

In your case you'd be better off installing the 32bit gcc and libc:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev:i386 gcc:i386
```

It will install the 32-bit libc development and gcc packages, and all depending packages (all 32bit versions), next to your 64-bit installation without breaking it.

Comment: Be aware that 64-bit gcc will be uninstalled if existing (though the libraries will remain)