# Application- how to compile 32-bit app on 64 bit host?

Tags: gcc, 64-bit, 32-bit, ubuntu-15.04

Host: Ubuntu 15.04

The compilation appeared the following messages:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have checked the following question&answer but it does not answer my question.

[How to Compile 32-bit Apps on 64-bit Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355436/how-to-compile-32-bit-apps-on-64-bit-ubuntu)

I tried to install the dependency as mentioned in the post.

```
sudo apt-get install lib32gcc-4.8-dev
```

I got the following pop up.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lib32gcc-4.8-dev : Depends: libx32gcc1 (>= 1:4.8.4-1ubuntu15) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libx32asan0 (>= 4.8.4-1ubuntu15) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I installed the following dependency:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-multilib : Depends: gcc-4.9-multilib (>= 4.9.2-1~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Please advice if you have any idea.

Comment: build-essential package installed? libc6-dev-i386 installed?

Comment: yea, both packages are installed.