# rust compile x86 library on x86_64 machine

Tags: rust, cross-compiling, rust-cargo

I have ubuntu x86_64 container and `cargo build` goes well.
But i need to build x86 library version too.
As far as I understand i need to add i686 toolchain and target.

```
rustup target add i686-unknown-linux-gnu done successful
```

```
rustup toolchain install stable-i686-unknown-linux-gnu finished with error
```

```
$ rustup toolchain install stable-i686-unknown-linux-gnu
info: syncing channel updates for 'stable-i686-unknown-linux-gnu'
info: latest update on 2018-11-08, rust version 1.30.1 (1433507eb 2018-11-07)
info: downloading component 'rustc'
info: downloading component 'rust-std'
info: downloading component 'cargo'
info: downloading component 'rust-docs'
info: installing component 'rustc'
info: installing component 'rust-std'
info: installing component 'cargo'
info: installing component 'rust-docs'

  stable-i686-unknown-linux-gnu installed - (error reading rustc version)
```

and

```
$ rustup  default stable-i686
info: using existing install for 'stable-i686-unknown-linux-gnu'
info: default toolchain set to 'stable-i686-unknown-linux-gnu'

  stable-i686-unknown-linux-gnu unchanged - (error reading rustc version)
```

Do I missed something or took wrong approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of changing your toolchain, you have to add the target to your current toolchain (make sure to switch back to your original toolchain first).

```
$ rustup target install i686-unknown-linux-gnu
$ cargo build --target=i686-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Of course, you need to install the 32-bit libraries on your system as well, e.g. on ubuntu you install them by

```
$ sudo apt install gcc-multilib
```

(for more information about that see [How to Compile 32-bit Apps on 64-bit Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355436/how-to-compile-32-bit-apps-on-64-bit-ubuntu))

Comment: Thank you. It was helpful. but I got stuck with the next step.
error: failed to run custom build command for `openssl-sys v0.9.39`
Problem with x86_64 build I solved by installing `libssl-dev`
But installing libssl-dev:i386 did not solve error on crosscompile.
btw it is not Ubuntu i have. Debian stretch

Comment: The full error message would be helpful (and maybe worth another question).

Comment: Problem resolved by pointing OPENSSL_DIR to right place.
Yes, i should make a new question for it. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Bottom link is a great article. Also `cargo` make everything so easy.

```bash
cargo new --bin rust
     Created binary (application) `rust` package

cd rust
cargo run

   Compiling rust v0.1.0 (/home/user/Documents/rust)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.37s
     Running `target/debug/rust`
Hello, world!

cat ~/.cargo/config
───────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
       │ File: /home/user/.cargo/config
───────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1   │ [target.x86_64-unknown-linux-musl]
   2   │ linker = "x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc"
   3   │ 
   4   │ [target.x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu]
   5   │ linker = "x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc"
───────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

cargo run
   Compiling rust v0.1.0 (/home/user/Documents/rust)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.10s
     Running `target/debug/rust`
I love programming.

cargo build --release --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
   Compiling rust v0.1.0 (/home/user/Documents/rust)
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.31s
```

- https://burgers.io/cross-compile-rust-from-arm-to-x86-64